# sign in with linkedin hubspot

Tags: linkedin-api, hubspot

I'm looking to find out if I can use the "Sign In with LinkedIn" feature / API with forms from HubSpot. I asked HubSpot about it and this was their response:

> The auto-fill feature on LinkedIn sounds like it could be very efficient, but I am not too familiar with it. Judging by the link you sent, it looks like this feature may be limited to certain users. The article says that it may still be in beta and the author is not sure how LinkedIn is granting access to the feature. I recommend getting in touch with LinkedIn support to find out if it is available and how to add it. If they are able to provide you with an API key and instructions to insert the code, I would be happy to look into it further.

Could you provide any help following their response?
I don't have much API knowledge at all, and your support email told me to submit on here!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2):

HubSpot does have a new connection feature with LinkedIn Sales Navigator.

https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/integrations/how-to-connect-hubspot-crm-and-linkedin-sales-navigator

Answer (score 0):

I've found this page very helpful for me: http://hsfox.com/sign-in-with-linkedin-for-hubspot

Also please find below answer from HubSpot

"To push information that is in the form fields to be auto-populated with LinkedIn and then pushed into your portal database would require an integration with our Forms API and the LinkedIn sign-in API:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

This is currently not possible natively in HubSpot, but can be done using some development work. I would recommend working with a developer to achieve this or alternatively you can reach out to our developer forums"

Hope it helps
Best
Matteo